# Проблемы с локалью

Tags: php

Изначально сервер настроен на Россию.

```
<?php

    print_r(setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL));
    echo strftime('%c');
    setlocale(LC_ALL,'sv_SE.ISO-8859-1');
    echo strftime('%c');
    print_r(setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL));

?>
```

Локаль не меняется и время тоже. Разница должна быть 2 часа.

Answer (score 1):

php http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.configuration.php#ini.intl.default-locale

.htaccess SetEnv